# php retrieve specific data onclick from database in a list format

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php include ("../navbar.php"); ?>
    
    <?php include("../conn.php"); 
        $query = "select * from semi_synthetic";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     ?>
    
    
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="compound_report_card">
        <h2>Compound Report</h2>
        
        <div class="card-content">
        
    <?php
    //Check If Id Isset.
    
        if(isset($_GET["CHIHBT_ID"]))
    
       //Display Id On A Webpage.
       echo "<p>Calculated Properties of : " . $_GET[ "CHIHBT_ID" ] . "</p>"; 
    
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        
    ?>
    
    
     <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )) {
                    ?>
    
             <ul>
                 <li>Canonical smiles :   <?php echo $row['smile_notation']; ?> </li>
                 <li> Molecular weight :   <?php echo $row['molecular_weight']; ?></li>
                 <li> Heavy atoms :    <?php echo $row['number_of_heavy_atoms']; ?></li>
                 <li> Aeromatic heavy atoms :   <?php echo $row['number_of_aeromatic_heavy_atoms']; ?></li>
                 <li> Rotatable bonds :  <?php echo $row['number_of_rotatable_bonds']; ?></li>
                 <li> H bond acceptors :  <?php echo $row['number_of_h_bond_acceptors']; ?></li>
                 <li> H bond donors:    <?php echo $row['number_of_h_bond_donors']; ?></li>
                 <li> Tpsa A**2 :   <?php echo $row['tpsa']; ?></li>
    
                </ul>
    
    
    <?php } ?>     
    
     </div>            
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <?php include ("../footer.php");   ?>
```

so this is my new code and i am displaying data on web from my database and . So what i am trying to do is i have a lot of id's and i want that  when i click on any id the data of that id from
database should get displayed. So the current situation is that when i am clicking on one id whole data from that table is getting displayed and i want only one to get displayed. I want onlyspecific data from every id that i click. So the problem i think is in while loop so please see that also

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:** Your code is getting all records and isn't querying against your selected ID.

**What you need to do:** Add selected ID in query to get specific result. Like shown below:

**Update:** From What I understand `$_GET["CHIHBT_ID"]` is your ID, right? Change this code in your script:

```
<?php include("../conn.php");
$query = "select * from semi_synthetic";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
```

To

```
<?php include("../conn.php");
$query = "select * from semi_synthetic";
?>
```

Then, change the following code:

```
<?php
//Check If Id Isset.

if (isset($_GET["CHIHBT_ID"]))

    //Display Id On A Webpage.
    echo "<p>Calculated Properties of : " . $_GET["CHIHBT_ID"] . "</p>";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

?>
```

With this:

```
<?php
//Check If Id Isset.

if (isset($_GET["CHIHBT_ID"])) {
    $query .= ' WHERE CHIHBT_ID = ' . $_GET["CHIHBT_ID"]; // add selected id in query

    //Display Id On A Webpage.
    echo "<p>Calculated Properties of : " . $_GET["CHIHBT_ID"] . "</p>";
}


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); // run query

?>
```

and that's it.

Comment: buddy check my new code and and please give y any solution for this i have changed my code and i have mentioned everything up there that what is it that i want

Comment: @shroud, I have updated the code, that should do it.

Comment: the thing is i have to get data according to the id means if i click on id1 i should get the data of id1  and if i click on id2  i should get the data of id2 like this

Comment: Hassay i want to get data display data according to the id  from my database and not for any specific id when i click on id1  i should get data of id1 if i click on id2  i should get data of id2 and so on like this with every id

Comment: How to select one data row by id and display using PHP and MYSQL query?

Comment: help me with this bro

Comment: Where is the code where you are displaying the IDs?

Comment: this is the code where i am displaying id'ds

Comment: this is code for the page where the data is getting displayed when i am clicking on id's

Comment: Then I have correctly added the code, please check closely, how I am updating `$query` to include the selected `CHIHBT_ID` from `$_GET` param